# Using the Parcel build tool, how can I control the locations of my output files?

Tags: parceljs

I'm following the official guide for Parcel 2.

By default parcel takes your input files and dumps them all in the same output directory.

The vast majority of developers have specific directory layouts for our projects. So parcel must offer a way for its users to put files and directories where we want them to go.

But I can't documentation for configuring output file layout.

How do I control where output files are created? And how to rename them?

For example, if I'm working with `projectroot/src/js/index.js`, how can I output to `projectroot/dist/js/bundle.js`